# TIFF image merge colour distortion

Tags: geotiff-tiff, merge, color

I am trying to merge 4 TIFF files and the resulting merge is coming out with some odd colour distortions. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the steps you followed to "merge 4 TIF files", and some detail as to what distortion you are seeing (a sample of what it should look like from the originals may help)